# "Do the names of the indigenous peoples of South America have a plural form?"

Tags: número-gramatical

More years ago than I care to count I was a student in high school. At that time I learned that the names of indigenous peoples have no plural form, and we must say "o Pataxó" and "os Pataxó". A Google search, however, has produced a considerable number of hits for "Os Guaranis". Not more than for "Os Guarani", it's true, but not a derisory figure either: approximately 80,000 hits for [**"Os Guarani"**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22os+guarani%22&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=%22os+guarani%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.12903j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) versus 45,000 for [**"Os Guaranis"**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22os+guarani%22&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=%22os+guarani%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.12903j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22os+guaranis%22).

My question is: what's the correct plural form for the name of the indigenous peoples of South America such as "Tupi", "Guarani", "Pataxó", "Caeté", etc.

Comment: Segundo os dicionários online esses nomes têm plural regular com ***s***; estão indicados como de dois géneros, mas não dois números. Em muitos casos, empregam mesmo o plural regular nas definições. Por exemplo no Aulete,  [dos guaranis](http://www.aulete.com.br/guarani), [dos pataxós](http://www.aulete.com.br/patax%C3%B3), [aos caetés](http://www.aulete.com.br/caet%C3%A9). – Jacinto

Comment: @Jacinto   Qunado os dicionários dizem uma coisa e o povo outra, eu paro  pra pensar.   Ao que me parece, pelo menos após uma procura no Google, usa-se muito mais "Os Guarani" do que "Os Guaranis".  Veja o link da questão para a procura que fiz para ambas as formas.  Como explicar isso?

Comment: @Jacinto  Can it be that it has two plural forms?

Comment: Well, there definitely are two plural form in use.

Comment: Deve-se usar 'Os índios Guarani' quando se fala do povo "Para os índios Guarani, a terra é a origem da vida.", ou 'Os Guaranis' quando se fala de certos índios "Muitos guaranis foram catequizados e abandonaram suas aldeias."

Comment: @AndréLyra   Could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: @AndréLyra   Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O plural de um nome é uma convenção. E o facto objetivo é que estão em uso dois plurais para os nomes dos povos indígenas do Brasil: um plural regular (*o guarani* versus *os guaranis*) e um plural irregular sem s que coincide com o singular, ou seja nome de dois números (*o/os guarani*). A tabela abaixo mostra que nuns casos predomina o plural regular; noutros o irregular (mostro a contagem inicial do Google, seguida da contagem na ‘ultima’ página, mais baixa, que exclui “resultados similares”).

**Resultados do Google**

---

```
Google geral             Guarani        Pataxó       Caeté         Tupi       Ianomâmi
Os + plural sem s      81.900/240    16.300/214    1.010/115    15.100/271    1.710/222
Os + plural regular    46.400/332    10.700/294    4.430/271    42.400/271    8.220/283
```

---

```
Google Books             Guarani        Pataxó       Caeté         Tupi       Ianomâmi
Os + plural sem s       2.830/82         33/33       18/18       1.640/66       12/12
Os + plural regular     3.020/74         35/35       43/43       2.870/65       38/38
```

---

Os dicionários que consultei—Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (Lisboa, 2001), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/guarani), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=patax%C3%B3), [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/caet%C3%A9) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ianom%C3%A2mi)—registam para todos os nomes que vi apenas os plurais regulares. Também é só plurais regulares que encontro na [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario), [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/simplesearch.php?action=lemma&lemma=136870&highlight=%5Ecra%C3%B4$) e [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum da CPLP](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=176004&highlight=caxinau%C3%A1) (neste último é preciso clicar em “flexões” para ver os plurais).

O plural regular não carece de qualquer justificação: limita-se a seguir a tradição da nossa língua. Como escreve a [*Folha de São Paulo* no seu *Manual de Redação*](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/circulo/manual_texto_i.htm) (entrada *indígena/índio*):

> Na **Folha**, nomes de nações, povos e tribos indígenas do Brasil são flexionados como os de qualquer etnia, povo ou nação: os tupis, os ianomâmis, os bantos, os apaches, os franceses, os mexicanos, os lapões.

Ao que consegui apurar, o plural sem s vem da Convenção para a Grafia dos Nomes Tribais de 1953 da Associação Brasileira de Antropologia ([texto completo](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41616540?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) acessível mediante registo; [resumo](http://www.juliomelatti.pro.br/notas/n-cgnt.pdf)). O objetivo da Convenção era usar em trabalhos científicos nomes tão fiéis quanto possível ao original na língua indígena. Daí o uso de normas gráficas diferentes da grafia oficial portuguesa de modo a representar sem ambiguidade uma boa aproximação à pronúncia indígena (usando por exemplo o y para representar a semiconsoante que nós grafamos com i em *h**i**ato*), e usar o mesmo nome para o singular e plural porque o nome na língua original poderia não ter plural ou não formar plural com s.

Mas agora há aqui duas coisas importantes. A Associação Brasileira de Antropologia pretendia apenas facilitar a comunicação no trabalho científico; nunca sugeriu que as suas normas fossem adotadas na grafia oficial. E mesmo para o trabalho científico, o artigo 21 prevê a grafia e flexões portuguesas para nomes de origem portuguesa ou “morficamente aportuguesados” [(texto completo)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41616540?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). Isto valeria, por exemplo, para *guarani* e *tupi*, que são formas aportuguesadas incorporadas na língua há séculos.

Esta posição parece-me absolutamente razoável. Não compete a um associação profissional propor para uso geral uma grafia e gramática alternativas. Mas obviamente o plural sem s saltou para usos não científicos, e independentemente de a grafia ter ou não sido adaptada às normas do português.

De algumas coisas que encontrei, como [este *Povos Indígenas e Tolerância: Construindo Práticas de Respeito e Solidariedade* editado por Luís Grupioni e outros (2001, p. 65-8)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=-XCZDv9abG0C&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=plural%20dos%20nomes%20de%20povos%20ind%C3%ADgenas&source=bl&ots=YOxIHalQMT&sig=xEEjR-xN9GlSVZNHAo3HYrsjznc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7y7a6nb_QAhUJWRQKHTVCDnsQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=plural%20dos%20nomes%20de%20povos%20ind%C3%ADgenas&f=false), fiquei com a sensação que a adoção destas normas alternativas na linguagem corrente é ou foi em parte alimentada por um ativismo político que procura através da grafia e gramática alternativas afirmar os direitos e identidade dos povos indígenas. Isto é mais óbvio na insistência na maiúscula inicial para os gentílicos indígenas: *Guarani, Pataxó*, contra a norma da grafia oficial, *guarani, brasileiro, português, chinês*. Mas também em geral no querer ter normas próprias que reflitam a língua original, ainda que mediada pelas convenções dos antropólogos.

Naturalmente cada um escreverá como achar melhor. Mas para mim escrever *os guarani* ou *os ianomâmi* para maior aproximação à lingua original não faz sentido. A língua original é a língua original, e a língua portuguesa é a língua portuguesa. Em inglês o plural é *the English*, mas nós escrevemos *os ingleses*, não *os inglês* ou *os English*. Do mesmo modo é *os italianos* e não *os italiani*; e *os espanhóis* e não *os españoles*.

E quem quiser uma posição mais contundente contra grafias e gramáticas alternativas pode ler a [*Dica 158* do Professor Paulo Hernandes](http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/dicas/001/dica158.html).

Comment: Faz muito sentido dizer que "a adoção destas normas alternativas na linguagem corrente é ou foi em parte alimentada por um ativismo político que procura através da grafia e gramática alternativas afirmar os direitos e identidade dos povos indígenas."  Não havia pensado nisso.  Ativismo político e querer ser políticamente correto por vezes interferem naquilo que não deveriam.  Excelente resposta.

Comment: @Centaurus Imagino, que seja também por simples imitação/gosto pela novidade. Mas de facto acho que os argumentos avançados não fazem sentido (vê *Povos indígenas e Tolerância*). Querer que se escreva *krahô* e não *craô* porque se escreve *Kubitscheck* e não *Cubicheque*, ignorando que escrevemos *espanhóis* e não *españoles*. Há no entanto questões muito relevantes. Há povos que simplesmente não se reconhecem nos nomes que lhes deram: confusão do funcionário da FUNAI que não compreendia a língua; ou  nome depreciativo que lhes era dado por outra tribo hostil, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to André Lyra who posted the comment and was invited to post it as answer.

Segundo os etnólogos e antropólogos, nome de nação indígena não faz plural: os Tupi, os Caeté, os Pataxó.

> - ["Quando da chegada dos espanhóis e portugueses na América, por volta de 1500, os Guarani já formavam um conjunto de povos com a mesma origem."](http://www.funai.gov.br/index.php/ascom/1947-historia-e-cultura-guarani)
> - ["Os Guarani são conhecidos por distintos nomes: Chiripá, Kainguá, Monteses, Baticola, Apyteré, Tembekuá, entre outros. No entanto, sua autodenominação é Avá, que significa, em Guarani, “pessoa”. Este povo vive em um território que compreende regiões no Brasil, Bolívia, Paraguai e Argentina e se diferencia internamente..."](https://pib.socioambiental.org/pt/povo/guarani)

Quando nos referimos a determinados indios daquela etnia, no entanto, o plural se faz com o usual acréscimo de s. "Muitos guaranis foram catequizados e abandonaram suas aldeias."

> - [Os Guaranis que vieram do sul do País na década de 60 mantêm suas características como: a língua, a religião, o artesanato e suas manifestações culturais.](http://www.aracruz.es.gov.br/turismo/atracoes-turisticas/19/)
> - [Os guaranis que atualmente habitam o litoral também conhecem a relação das fases da Lua com as marés.](http://www2.uol.com.br/sciam/reportagens/mitos_e_estacees_no_ceu_tupi-guarani.html)

**Addendum**

Uma pesquisa rápida no Google mostra [**4540**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22o+guarani+%C3%A9%22&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=%22o+guarani+%C3%A9%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9583j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22os+guarani+s%C3%A3o%22&tbas=0) entradas para "os Guarani são" e [**3280**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22o+guarani+%C3%A9%22&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=%22o+guarani+%C3%A9%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9583j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22os+guaranis+s%C3%A3o%22) para "os Guaranis são".

Comment: ***Os** Guarani **são*** é plural: o que queres dizer é que *Guarani* enquanto nação é um substantivo plural. *Os Guarani* para ‘nação’/ *os guaranis* para ‘indivíduos’ poderá ser a prática, ou mesmo a doutrina, entre os etnólogos e antropólogos (os teus 4 exemplos não demonstram que seja; encontro contraexemplos). Mas que seja: os etnólogos e antropólogos não são autoridade em matéria de língua.  Todos os dicionários que vi têm *guaranis* para a nação. (Continua.)

Comment: E não é só dicionários. Por exemplo, no manual de redação da Folha de São Paulo: «Na Folha , nomes de nações, povos e tribos indígenas do Brasil são flexionados como os de qualquer etnia, povo ou nação: os tupis, os ianomamis, os bantos, os apaches, os franceses, os mexicanos, os lapões.»

Comment: @Jacinto podias formular uma resposta ;)

Comment: @Jacinto   Acrescentei mais uma informação a respeito.